# Apply a function to each row of a column in a dataframe to create a new column

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I'm having trouble applying a function to each row within a column of a dataframe to create a new column, and would appreciate some guidance. The function is question is a maxplus operator

```
maxplus  <- function(x, lb=0){max(x, lb)}
```

I have a dataframe `r_df` which looks like this:

```
head(r_df)

      Date    GS3M_ret
1 Jan 1990 0.006583333
2 Feb 1990 0.006666667
3 Mar 1990 0.006808333
4 Apr 1990 0.006700000
5 May 1990 0.006675000
6 Jun 1990 0.006658333
```

I want to apply `maxplus` to the last column to get a positive restriction of GS3M_ret. Using the operator directly gives me a single number, which is not what i want (i want each row of test to be the maximum of the corresponding row of GS3M_ret and 0)

```
maxplus(r_df[, "GS3M_ret"], 0)

        Date     GS3M_ret        test
1   Jan 1990 6.583333e-03 0.006808333
2   Feb 1990 6.666667e-03 0.006808333
3   Mar 1990 6.808333e-03 0.006808333
4   Apr 1990 6.700000e-03 0.006808333
5   May 1990 6.675000e-03 0.006808333'
```

I have tried apply, tapply, sapply, etc. and get a variant of the following

```
apply(r_df[, "GS3M_ret"], 1, maxplus)
```

> Error in apply(r_df[, "GS3M_ret"], 1, maxplus) :  dim(X) must have a positive length

or

```
tapply(r_df[, "GS3M_ret"], 1, maxplus)
```

> Error in tapply(r_df[, "GS3M_ret"], 1, maxplus) : arguments must have same length

I'm clearly doing some wrong (and wrong in an elementary way), but haven't been able to solve my problem. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not going to attempt to recreate your code, but from the sound of your question, the base R,  transform(), function might solve your need.  This function will add a new variable to an existing df (somewhat similar to mutate) but much simpler.     Here are two examples using transform.                       
      transform (airquality, Ozone = -Ozone)                                                                                                                      
      transform(airquality, new = -Ozone, Temp = (Temp-32)/1.8)

Answer (score 1):

`max` returns a single number. To test for each number separately use `pmax`.

```
maxplus  <- function(x, lb=0) pmax(x, lb)

maxplus(df$GS3M_ret)
#Or specify lb
#maxplus(df$GS3M_ret, 0)
#[1] 0.006583333 0.006666667 0.006808333 0.006700000 0.006675000 0.006658333
```

Comment: Thank you very much - it works like a charm. The apply / tapply approaches still don't work though. Is there something else that needs to be done for those to work?

Comment: `tapply` is used when you want to apply some function by group, here we don't have any group so `tapply` is not needed. `apply` is used to apply function row-wise. we can use it here but it doesn't make sense because `pmax` is vectorized and can process vector of values together.

Comment: Now I'm really curious (and a little confused). I started using apply with max instead of pmax and got nowhere..pmax, in contrast, worked like a charm. What is the root cause of my earlier error with apply?

Comment: @ThomasPhilips Check the output of `r_df[, "GS3M_ret"]` it is a vector and not a dataframe. `apply` needs a dataframe or matrix as 1st argument you are passing a vector to it, hence it gives you an error. Your attempt is similar to doing `apply(1:10, 1, sum)` which gives the same error because `1:10` is a vector and not a dataframe, this is the root cause of your error with `apply`.

Comment: That explains it. I did not check the class / type of the subset I created. Thanks a mill, both for the solution and for the clear explanation of my error.